# Properties of the set of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{|x^{2}-1|}{|x|+1}< \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, contest-math

This is from an MCQ contest.

> Let $$\displaystyle A=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \dfrac{|x^{2}-1|}{|x|+1}< \dfrac{1}{2} \right\} $$ Then:
>
> - $1]$ $A$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$
> - $2]$ $A$ is a bounded set of $\mathbb{R}$
> - $3]$ $A$ is not an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and is unbounded
> - $4]$ None of the other statements is correct

My thoughts

At first, we discuss the cases

- if $x>0$ then $|x|+1=x+1=|x+1|$ thus
  \begin{align}
  x\in A &\iff \dfrac{|x^{2}-1|}{|x|+1}< \dfrac{1}{2} \\
  &\iff \dfrac{|x-1||x+1|}{|x|+1}< \dfrac{1}{2}\\
  &\iff \dfrac{|x-1|(|x|+1)}{|x|+1}< \dfrac{1}{2}\\
  &\iff |x-1| < \dfrac{1}{2}\\
  &\iff \dfrac{1}{2} < x < \dfrac{3}{2}
  \end{align}
- if $x<0$ then $|x|+1=-x+1=|-x+1|=|x-1|$ thus
  \begin{align}
  x\in A &\iff \dfrac{|x^{2}-1|}{|x|+1}< \dfrac{1}{2} \\
  &\iff \dfrac{|x-1||x+1|}{|x|+1}< \dfrac{1}{2}\\
  &\iff \dfrac{|x+1|(|x|+1)}{|x|+1}< \dfrac{1}{2}\\
  &\iff |x+1| < \dfrac{1}{2}\\
  &\iff \dfrac{-3}{2} < x < \dfrac{-1}{2}
  \end{align}
- $x=0$ then $1<\dfrac{1}{2} $ thus $0\notin A$

the sum up $$A=\left(\dfrac{-3}{2},\dfrac{-1}{2}\right)\cup\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{2}\right)$$

- Is my proof correct
- how can i proof that the others statement are false

Comment: Please no `\dfrac` in titles if you can avoid them (and you can).

Comment: @Did  I didn't do it on purpose so nest time i'll aviod it

Answer (score 2):

You might shorten the proof noting that, as $x^2=\lvert x\rvert^2$, one may as well suppose $x\ge 0$, and extend the results to the case $ x\le 0 $ by symmetry.

For the case $x=0$, you can incorporate it to the first case, i.e.  consider the case $x\ge 0$ instead of $x>0$.

You get the solution: $\;A=\Bigl(\dfrac12,\dfrac32\Bigr)\cup\Bigl(-\dfrac32,-\dfrac12\Bigr)$, which is the union of two *disjoint* intervals, and thus is not an interval: indeed $-1$ and $1$ lie in $A$, so if $A$ were an interval, all numbers between $-1$ and $1$ would belong to $A$, which clearly is not the case.

$A$ is bounded because for all $x\in A$, one has $\lvert x\rvert<\dfrac32$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why it's bounded set and not interval please

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for the second case $x < 0$, the 3rd line in your equivalences has a typo, but otherwise it looks fine. Since you solved for $A$ explicitly, you can determine whether it's an interval and whether it's bounded. An interval set must contain all intermediate points between $x$ and $y$ if $x$ and $y$ are in your set, it's easy to see $0$ is not in your set.

Comment: thanks now i see why it's not intervalle

Answer (score 0):

That $A$ is *open* does not mean it is an *interval* -- you set is a union of intervals, but not an interval.

$A$ is certainly bounded, so (2) is true and others are false.

Comment: Please see my completed answer.